# can't read json data passed to $.ajax to php curl

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, curl

I have passed data to ajax to curl but can't  parse json data which I get in ajax call my ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/curl_call.php',
         type:"POST",
        data:
    {
        url_path:"http://localhost/login/", 
        data:"name=bddd&password=abc",
    },
    crossDomain: true,
        processData: true,
        success:function(response)
    {
              res_par=JSON.parse(response);
               alert(res_par["success"]);
            }
 )};
```

**curl_call.php:**

```
function curl_load($url,$post_data){
curl_setopt($ch=curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
```

}

```
if((isset($_POST["url_path"]))&&($_POST["url_path"]=="http://localhost/api/login/"))
{
echo json_encode(json_decode(curl_load($_POST["url_path"],$_POST["data"])));
}
```

can't parsed return data why?

Comment: Your code samples are inconsistent. You are calling `$.ajax` with `url_path` set to `http://localhost/login/` but in the PHP script, you are expecting it to be set to `http://localhost/api/login/`, which fails and the `curl_load` function is probably never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you need some debugging in your scripts. Try the following in order:

1. First of all, why do you `json_decode` and `json_encode` the same string?
2. Then, check if your response is a valid `JSON` string. You can try it here: http://json.parser.online.fr/
3. Are you sure that `response` is a valid property on your json?
4. Try adding this at the top of `curl_call.php`.

   header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
5. And replace the `success` function of your JS for the following, and then check your browser's console:

   success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
   }